# heif-convert: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: jpeg_write_icc_profile, version LIBJPEG_6.2

Tags: shell-script, debian, package-management, libraries, conversion

I have run heif-convert successfully not long ago but now I get this error:

```
>heif-convert bob.heic bob.jpeg
heif-convert: symbol lookup error: heif-convert: undefined symbol: jpeg_write_icc_profile, version LIBJPEG_6.2
```

Any idea how to fix this? I'm running Debian 10 testing. Apparently I have the newest versions of the packages `libheif-examples` and `libjpeg62-turbo` installed.